# Filter Out Blank Value Cells on Another Sheet In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I am trying to filter out empty rows from the USER INVENTORY MODEL sheet and show them all, without empty rows, in the TESTING sheet.  I have found a [website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/extract-values-from-non-blank-cells/33a8cd00-5233-4aaf-bfed-afc019e28980) that shows how to do this if the columns are next to each other but not when they are on different sheets.  Can anyone tell me how to modify the formula below to work on another sheet?

Below is the formula as I have it now"

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B$2:B$300,SMALL(IF('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B$2:B$300<>"",ROW('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B$2:B$300)),ROW(2:2))),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=INDEX('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B$2:INDEX('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B:B, MATCH("zzz", 'USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B:B)))/SIGN(LEN('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B$2:INDEX('USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B:B, MATCH("zzz", 'USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B:B)))), ROW(1:1)))
```

I have assumed that 'USER INVENTORY MODEL'!B:B contains text values, not numbers.

Comment: Text values are the majority but I do have some number values.  How much of this will change if I do have number values?

Comment: To find the last true number value, change `MATCH("zzz", ...` to `MATCH(1e99, ...`. It is important to minimize the number of rows to process.